# "Local variable referenced before assignment" error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I get "local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment" error with my code. How should I resolve this?

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter


def proces():

  F=Entry.get(E1)
  m=Entry.get(E2)
  a=Entry.get(E3)
  if F ==0:
      answer=float(m)*float(a)
  if m ==0:       
      answer=float(F)/float(a)
  if a ==0:
      answer=float(F)/float(m)
  Entry.insert(E4,0,answer)
  print(answer)

#And the rest of the GUI coding goes here. 

top = Tkinter.Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="My calculator",).grid(row=0,column=1)
L2 = Label(top, text="Force",).grid(row=1,column=0)
L3 = Label(top, text="Weight",).grid(row=2,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="Accelaration",).grid(row=3,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="Solution",).grid(row=4,column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.grid(row=1,column=1)
E2 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E2.grid(row=2,column=1)
E3 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E3.grid(row=3,column=1)
E4 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E4.grid(row=4,column=1)
B=Button(top, text ="Solve",command = proces).grid(row=5,column=1,)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: just define `answer=0 or some vale` above `IF`, just think about if none of the condition satisfies what will be the value for answer ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please provide a [mcve] for the question you're asking as opposed to your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Give like this :

```
answer = "the value which you can give as default"
if F ==0:
  answer=float(m)*float(a)
if m ==0:       
  answer=float(F)/float(a)
if a ==0:
  answer=float(F)/float(m)
```

or

```
if F ==0:
  answer=float(m)*float(a)
elif m ==0:       
  answer=float(F)/float(a)
elif a ==0:
  answer=float(F)/float(m)
else :
  answer = "the value which you can give as default"
```

If none of the conditions is matching which value you want to assign to `answer`? that value you can give in mentioned place in that above answers

Comment: Nope it gives the answer as '0'

Comment: what are your other values ? Try to print answer in in each if and check it

Comment: tried printing answer after each if . Then nothing happens after I enter 2 numbers in 2 of 3 fields and press solve.Any help"?

Comment: I can help you but need to know what values you are passing to F,m and a ?

Comment: I don`t know exactly wt you meant. But I`m entering floating point numbers(or integers).

Comment: try print `F ,m and a`, then just mention here.

Comment: I got what you said . When I do this it prints 0 as answer. On a side note can you please tell me whether I have written           
    "Entry.insert(E4,0,answer)" corectly?

Comment: This _is_ the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value to variable 'answer' inside the if statement so its scope is limited to those if statements, simply initialize your variable answer before if statement.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do this? , Cus when I assign 'answer=0'  before is statements the solution(answer) prints out as 0 allways.

Comment: After initializing answer=0 If you are getting '0' as your answer at the end, this means none of the if conditions are being executed, so you've to check the values you are passing to F, m, a.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much for your quick replies.

I finally solved it .

All I had to do is make 
    if (variable)==0:
    to
    if len(variable)==0:

I hope anyone who get this problem in the future will find this helpful.